# AWS Cognito, why InititiateAuthResponse is null?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

i'm developing for the first time using AWS Cognito in Java.

I created a code for an Admin to create a User. The user will be automatically created with the status FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD. What i was going to do now is a simple login, but if the system return a CHANGE_PASSWORD challenge, then it will open another window where the user should input old password and new password, then submit them to cognito.

The code i used to create a user through AdminCreateUser is the following:

```
 // Creating instance of client CognitoIdentityProvider
        CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder().region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1).build();

        AdminCreateUserRequest requestUserCreation = AdminCreateUserRequest.builder()
                .username(usernameTextField.getText())
                .desiredDeliveryMediums(DeliveryMediumType.EMAIL)
                .userAttributes(AttributeType.builder()
                        .name("email")
                        .value(emailTextField.getText())
                        .build())
                .userPoolId("xxxxx")
                .build();

        // Sending sign up request
        AdminCreateUserResponse responseUserCreation = cognitoClient.adminCreateUser(requestUserCreation);

        // Saving the group we want to put the user in through a combobox
        String groupname = (String) groupComboBox.getValue();

        UserType newUser = responseUserCreation.user();
        GroupType group = GroupType.builder().groupName(groupname).build();

        AdminAddUserToGroupRequest addUserToGroupRequest = AdminAddUserToGroupRequest.builder()
                .userPoolId("xxxxx")
                .username(newUser.username())
                .groupName(groupname)
                .build();

        AdminAddUserToGroupResponse addUserToGroupResult = cognitoClient.adminAddUserToGroup(addUserToGroupRequest);
```

This code works. When i submit this through a button, an email arrives to the user i created, and it also shows in my Amazon Cognito console.

Now the login part is giving me trouble.

As i said, i want to open another windows which has the right form for resetting the password. I still haven't thought about the implementation for resetting the password because my login doesnt' work, so i will implement this later.

This is my login code:

```
public void Login(ActionEvent event) {

            final String CLIENT_ID = cs.getAppClientId();
            final String USER_NAME = userNameTextField.getText();
            final String PASSWORD = passwordTextField.getText();
            final Region region = cs.getRegion();

            CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
                    .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
                    .region(region)
                    .build();


            InitiateAuthRequest authRequest = InitiateAuthRequest.builder()
                    .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                    .authFlow("USER_PASSWORD_AUTH")
                    .authParameters(createAuthParameters(USER_NAME, PASSWORD))
                    .build();

            try {
                InitiateAuthResponse authResult = cognitoClient.initiateAuth(authRequest);

                if (authResult.challengeName() != null) {
                    if (authResult.challengeName().equals(ChallengeNameType.NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED.toString())) {
                        try {
                            reimpostaPassword.apriSchermataReimpostaPassword(event);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // The authentication was successful
                        AuthenticationResultType authenticationResult = authResult.authenticationResult();
                        System.out.println("Access token: " + authenticationResult.accessToken());
                    }
                }
            } catch (NotAuthorizedException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect username or password");
            } catch (PasswordResetRequiredException e) {
                System.out.println("Password reset is required for the user");
            }
```

When i fill my form with the right username and password, it gives me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.AuthenticationResultType.accessToken()" because "authenticationResult" is null
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Login.LoginController.Login(LoginController.java:101)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Login.LoginController.clickPulsanteLogin(LoginController.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 51 more
```

The line that gives me error is this:

```
System.out.println("Access token: " + authenticationResult.accessToken());
```

This is an odd behaviour, because this means that the 'if the challenge is new password required' control fails, so i'm a little stuck here.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on this use case now. To get a very similiar example working, I created a user pool with an App that lets me use these Authentication flows.

[image]

When I execute my  AWS SDK for Java V2 code that uses **identityProviderClient.adminInitiateAuth()** - I successfully get an Access Token - as shown here.

[image]

WHen i speicfy an incorrect password, I get exception as expected.

Here is a Java code example. To run this Java code example, create a new user in the specified user pool with a temporary password. You will get back a challenge type value of NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED in the response.

You cannot read the access token. This code then changes the temporary password to a permanent password. Now the user can log in with the permanent password and you can read the access token.

```
public class GetAccessToken {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <clientId> <poolId> <username> <tempPassword> <permanentPassword>\n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    clientId - The app client Id value that you can get from the AWS CDK script.\n\n" +
            "    poolId - The pool Id that has the user. \n\n" +
            "    username - The new user name with a temp password. \n\n" +
            "    tempPassword - The temp password. \n\n" +
            "    permanentPassword - The permanent password. \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 5) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        String clientId = args[0];
        String poolId = args[1];
        String username = args[2];
        String tempPassword = args[3];
        String permanentPassword = args[4];

        CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();

        boolean wasLoggedIn = getToken(identityProviderClient, clientId, username, tempPassword, poolId);
        if (wasLoggedIn)
            System.out.println(username +" successfully authenticated");
        else {
            // Change the temp password to a permanent one and then call getToken() again. Now you will
            // get access tokens.
            changeTempPassword(identityProviderClient, username, permanentPassword, poolId);
            getToken(identityProviderClient, clientId, username, permanentPassword, poolId);
            System.out.println(username +" successfully authenticated");
        }
    }

    public static boolean getToken(CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient, String clientId, String username, String password, String poolId) {
        final Map<String, String> authParams = new HashMap<>();
        authParams.put("USERNAME", username);
        authParams.put("PASSWORD", password);

        AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = AdminInitiateAuthRequest.builder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .userPoolId(poolId)
            .authParameters(authParams)
            .authFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)
            .build();

        try {
            // If you specify an incorrect username/password, an exception is thrown.
            AdminInitiateAuthResponse response = identityProviderClient.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);

            // Get the Challenge type
            if (response.challengeNameAsString() == null) {
                System.out.println("Access Token Type : " + response.authenticationResult().tokenType());
                System.out.println("Access Token : " + response.authenticationResult().accessToken());
                return true;
            } else if (response.challengeNameAsString().compareTo("NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED") == 0) {
                System.out.println("The User must change their password. ");
            }

        } catch(CognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void changeTempPassword(CognitoIdentityProviderClient identityProviderClient, String username, String newPassword, String poolId){
        try {
            AdminSetUserPasswordRequest passwordRequest = AdminSetUserPasswordRequest.builder()
                .username(username)
                .userPoolId(poolId)
                .password(newPassword)
                .permanent(true)
                .build();

            identityProviderClient.adminSetUserPassword(passwordRequest);
            System.out.println("The password was successfully changed");

        } catch(CognitoIdentityProviderException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

***SO the reason why you get this NULL Exception is because you need to set the permanent password for the user. If the challengeName=NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED, you cannot read the access token.***

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You said that you changed the password using cli as an admin. Unfortunately, this is not the behaviour i want: i want the user to login, and if it's the first time he signs in, then a prompt appears to let him change this password.

Comment: That should work. I simply wanted to test adminInitiateAuth()  with a username/password.

Comment: See my Update that i created based on testing a new user without updating the password

Comment: I tried using your code, but it still gives me the null error. It sounds very strange

Comment: See my update where i talk about  Challenge type

Comment: If the challengeName=NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED, you cannot read the access token.

Comment: Let me get this right: my token is null because the challenge name is NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED, so my login fails. But doesn't that mean that a user should change its password WITHOUT loggin in? From what i understood, the flow should be: you sign in, but the authresponse has a challenge in it that requires you to change the password, you change the password, and now you'll be able to fully login. Moreover, having a null token and cannot reading a token sounds pretty different to me. I'm just telling you my doubts so i can better understand everything. I truly thank you for your time!

Comment: An access token in the response cannot be read (its null) if the challenge type is NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED. You can read that value in the response and then your app can prompt the user to provide an updated password. Once you do and the user logs in with the updated password, then you can get the access token. Your feedback is valid and I changed the Java logic based on it. See above Java code that now tests for NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED.

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much. I will now study how to reset the password, using the links you provided me!

Comment: I am glad it working and this interaction has improved this new Java code example for V2. It will be pub soon in https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/cognito.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251966/discussion-between-ric97-and-smac2020).